How do I generate a running total based on dates in Google Sheets using Query Function



Date
Income




03/12/2023
$400


03/19/2023
$200


03/21/2023
-$200


04/02/2024
$500


05/18/2024
$350


05/22/2024
-$100


05/31/2024
-$25.



I need some guidance on how to use query function to generate running total for above table. The table needs to be grouped by end of the month based on the year (Pivot for the year).
thanks in advance.
=query({Arrayformula('Cash-Flow'!$A$1:$B), Arrayformula(EOMONTH('Cash-Flow'!$A$1:$B,0)),Arrayformula(MONTH('Cash-Flow'!$A1:$B))}, "SELECT MONTH(Col1)+1, MAX(Col2)  group by MONTH(Col1)+1 PIVOT YEAR(Col1)", 1)

This only works within the boundary of the month and does not carry the running total to the next month.

what's the expected result?

Array formula and Query Functions
Problem Statement:
To use a query function to generate a running total. The table needs to be grouped by the end of the month based on the year.
I used two formulas to achieve the desired output based on how I understand your problem.
In my Cash-Flow tab, I used the formula:

=(TEXT(A2:A, "yyyy-mm"))

to format the dates into YYYY-MM.
In the Monthly Summary tab, I used the formula:

=QUERY('Cash-Flow'!B:C, "SELECT C, SUM(B) WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY C ORDER BY C", 1)

to summarize the income by month.
To calculate the running total, I added this formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="", "", SUMIF(ROW(B$2:B), "<=" & ROW(B2:B), B$2:B)))

Reference/s:
QUERY function
ARRAYFORMULA
